# identify a file with only a partially known name

Tags: vba, excel

I have one macro that saves files and naming pattern is Myfile_ddmmyyyy_hhmmss.rep (the ddmmyyyy_hhmmss stands for current date and time:) ).

What I struggle to achieve is to write a macro that would identify the file with the most recent date and time in the name. What I have is:

```
Sub App_FileSearch_Example()

Const SOME_PATH As String = "t:\"

Dim file As String
Do
file = Dir$(SOME_PATH & "MyFile_ddmmyyyy_hhmmss" & ".rep")

    If (Len(file) > 0) Then
    MsgBox "found " & file
    End If
Loop Until file = Dir$()
End Sub
```

The problem is that it infinitely finds the same file...
Thanks in advance,
Artur.

Comment: Would finding the file with the most recent Save date and time work?

Comment: Without reinventing the wheel  http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip97.htm provides a method using the filesystem date time, you could substitute this for your ddmmyyy_hhmmss cast to a datetime/ data type and check for newer on each file scanned...

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification to your code. It compiles but I have not tested it with a folder of .rep files.

```
Sub App_FileSearch_Example()
    Dim fn As String, tmp As String, theNewest As String, dtFn As Date
    Const SOME_PATH As String = "t:\"

    theNewest = "nothing found"
    fn = Dir$(SOME_PATH & "MyFile_*.rep")
    Do While CBool(Len(fn))
        tmp = Left(fn, InStr(1, fn, Chr(46)) - 1)       'truncate at the period
        tmp = Mid(tmp, InStr(1, tmp, Chr(95)) + 1, 99)  'split off at the first _
        tmp = Replace(tmp, Chr(95), Chr(32))            'replace the _ in the datetime
        If DateValue(tmp) > dtFn Then
            dtFn = DateValue(tmp)
            theNewest = fn
        End If
        fn = Dir$()
    Loop
    MsgBox "found " & theNewest
End Sub
```